# Validator: How to settle this error?

Tags: xhtml, character-encoding

I get this error in the validator:

```
Line 47, Column 187: character "&amp;" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data 
…num, silver diamonds. cartier tiffany & Co.  $18 WALKING LIBERTY DOLLARS   $15…



This message may appear in several cases: 
You tried to include the "<" character in your page: you should escape it as "&lt;"
You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&amp;", which is always safe.
Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a previous tag.
```

How to settle it?

Comment: Did you actually read the error?

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to escape an ampersand.

Replace `&` with `&amp;`.